# How to fix ambiguous when join is use USING

Tags: mysql

I tried to alias different parts of the code but no matter what i do i still get the error

> Column 'product_id' in from clause is ambiguous

The error become after i add this part of the code

```
LEFT JOIN oc_product_special ps ON ps.product_id = filter_counter.product_id AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW()))
```

Final code:

```
SELECT options.option_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN filter_counter.option_id = options.option_id THEN product_id END) total
    FROM filter_counter
    
    LEFT JOIN oc_product USING (product_id)
    LEFT JOIN oc_product_special ps ON ps.product_id = sd.product_id AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW()))
    
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT option_id FROM filter_counter ) AS options
    
    JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT sd1.product_id FROM filter_counter sd1
        WHERE manufacturer_id  IN (21) ) AS filter43 USING (product_id) 
        
        
            WHERE (CASE WHEN ps.price IS NULL THEN p.price BETWEEN 10 AND 50 WHEN ps.price IS NOT NULL THEN ps.price BETWEEN 10 AND 50 END)
        GROUP BY options.option_id
```

I tried to swap USING with ON and add Alias but still same error that i cant understand how to fix

```
SELECT options.option_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN sd.option_id = options.option_id THEN product_id END) total
    FROM filter_counter sd
    
    LEFT JOIN oc_product p ON p.product_id = sd.product_id
  LEFT JOIN oc_product_special ps ON ps.product_id = sd.product_id AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW()))
    
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT option_id FROM filter_counter) AS options
      
    JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM filter_counter
        WHERE manufacturer_id  IN (21) ) AS filter43 ON filter43.product_id = sd.product_id
        
            WHERE (CASE WHEN ps.price IS NULL THEN p.price BETWEEN 10 AND 50 WHEN ps.price IS NOT NULL THEN ps.price BETWEEN 10 AND 50 END)
        GROUP BY options.option_id
```

Comment: *USING (product_id)* collapses this column for joined tables only. If 3rd table joined later contains the same column then this column is not collapsed into. Moreover, in `a LEFT JOIN b USING (x)` the column name `x` matches `a.x` only.

Comment: You just need aliases for all the tables in the query.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN oc_product_special ps ON ps.product_id = sd.product_id` - `sd` alias is not defined.

Comment: Can I suggest not using USING

Comment: @Strawberry even i swap USING with ON still same problem

Comment: @Ivan not all the columns are qualified with the table name/alias.

Comment: Ivan, sure but that's a different question.

Comment: Check `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN sd.option_id = options.option_id THEN product_id END)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN filter_counter.option_id = options.option_id THEN product_id END) total
```

to

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN filter_counter.option_id = options.option_id THEN filter_counter.product_id END) total
```

Your added oc_product_special join made it ambiguous whether that was ps.product_id or filter_counter.product_id.

Answer (score 0):

In CASE WHEN clause the prodict_id is not fully qualified try using eg: sd.product_id

```
SELECT options.option_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN sd.option_id = options.option_id THEN sd.product_id END) total
    FROM filter_counter sd

    LEFT JOIN oc_product p ON p.product_id = sd.product_id
    LEFT JOIN oc_product_special ps ON ps.product_id = sd.product_id 
        AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW()))

    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT option_id FROM filter_counter) AS options
  
    JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT product_id 
            FROM filter_counter
            WHERE manufacturer_id  IN (21) 
    ) AS filter43 ON filter43.product_id = sd.product_id
    
    WHERE (CASE WHEN ps.price IS NULL THEN p.price BETWEEN 10 AND 50 WHEN ps.price IS NOT NULL THEN ps.price BETWEEN 10 AND 50 END)
    GROUP BY options.option_id
```

Answer (score -2):

Change:-

```
 COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN filter_counter.option_id = options.option_id THEN product_id END) total
```

To:-

COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN filter_counter.option_id = options.option_id THEN filter_counter.product_id END) product_id